# Using visNetwork to dynamically update nodes in R

Tags: r, layout, nodes, graph-visualization, visnetwork

the below snapshot visual is created using the "visNetwork" package. My requirement here is that I have to hard code the edges and also after using visHierarchicalLayout(), I am not able to see them in order, Please help me with a dynamic approach such that no matter how many numbers, I get consecutive numbers in order without hard code. Thanks and please help.

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:7, label = 1:7)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  to = c(2,3,4,5,6,7))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
visEdges(arrows = "to") %>% 
visHierarchicalLayout()
```

[image: Snapshot visual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using level attribute does the job, it aligns the network based on the order given.

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:7, label = 1:7, level = 1:7)
# Extract the id
num <- nodes$id
# Repeat the numbers
num2 <- rep(num, each = 2)
# Remove the first and last numbers
num3 <- num2[c(-1, -length(num2))]
#Create a data frame
edges <- as.data.frame(matrix(num3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
names(edges) <- c("from", "to")
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%") %>% 
visEdges(arrows = "to") %>% 
visHierarchicalLayout()
```

Comment: Great. I have upvoted your post. Since you copied and pasted my codes to build the edges data frame, it may make sense that I would also get some credits.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear in my previous comment. It is wrong to copy and paste others’ code without any acknowledgement or notice. In this case, you may want to give an upvote to my post since without my post your answer will be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create the `edges` data frame based on the `id` in the `nodes` data frame. Here is one option.

```
# Extract the id
num <- nodes$id

# Repeat the numbers
num2 <- rep(num, each = 2)

# Remove the first and last numbers
num3 <- num2[c(-1, -length(num2))]

# Create a data frame
edges <- as.data.frame(matrix(num3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
names(edges) <- c("from", "to")

edges
#   from to
# 1    1  2
# 2    2  3
# 3    3  4
# 4    4  5
# 5    5  6
# 6    6  7
```

Comment: thank you so much for replying and helping me here, however, as per my requirement, I also need help regarding arranging the plot such the node numbered "1" appears at the top and then the numbers follow sequentially, using visHierarchicalLayout(), this should be achieved but the output is again the same as in the visual above. Please help.

Comment: @AdamShaw I don't know how to do that. Perhaps others can help you.

Comment: @AdamShaw Thanks for accepting my post as the answer. However, I think Ashmin Kaul's answer is more complete. I have a suggestion. If you don't mind, could you accept Ashmin Kaul's answer but give me an upvote my post? The reason is I did develop a method to create `edges` data frame. If you think this effort is helpful, an upvote would be great.

Comment: @www, as you suggest, however, as I am progressing with visNetwork, I am getting more clarity using the functions, kindly help me with this post here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48126102/aligning-the-initial-node-of-the-visnetwork-at-the-top

Comment: @www I have a similar question but with specific cell structure. [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129820/how-to-create-molecular-cell-structure-and-custom-connectors-in-shiny). Can you please suggest how to approach this

Comment: @www, updated the question in new [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511969/how-to-define-node-positions-in-vis-network)